# Ruby on Rails - Custom token expiration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, postgresql

I'm currently migrating a Rails application running with Mongodb to move to Psql. There are some roadblocks and this is one of them that I'm investigating solutions for. Is there a way to set expiration index on a model attribute or an alternative solution to achieve similar functionality? This is how we have implemented in Mongo,

```
field :impersonate_token
index({ impersonate_token: 1 }, expire_after_seconds: 60)
```

This is a custom token with :impersonatable by devise. 
Please share if you know of a way to achieve this with Postgres.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Postgres doesn't have a counterpart feature.

[There is another question quite similar to yours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26046816/is-there-a-way-to-set-an-expiry-time-after-wich-a-data-entry-is-automatically) which may help you resolve this issue.

If you don't need to delete the row from your table then you could simply add an `expires_at` field which you set to the date-time when the token isn't valid anymore. Then you would be able to get the valid tokens by adding the following `where` method call.

```
Token.where('expires_at < ?', Time.zone.now)
```