# Dynamic job scheduler or Timer in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

**Case:**

A temporary record is inserted for a specific period of time *(eg now() for the next 5 minutes)*.

If *"appropriate action"* takes place within defined period *(eg now() + 2 minutes)* then the record gets deleted through a *delete statement*.

If period ends, the record should get **automatically** deleted.

At first sight, I would like to solve this **within** DB space.

**Possible solutions:**

I have found two tools which may help; **pg_cron** and **pgAgent**.
I am not sure if they would be set dynamically in real time, wouldn't they?

For example: *(expired_time) et = now() + 10 minutes*

```
SELECT cron.schedule('minutes(et) hours(et) * * *', $$DELETE FROM ... $$);
```

**Note:** Above syntax is indicative!

Is there any other way or tool to do that, **always** within DB?

Tia

Comment: I would suggest that you look into Redis instead - it has TTL (time to live) option for most of the data structures so they will be automatically purged after the specified time period (if not explicitly removed before that). Redis is more suitable for things like that. And with a recent PostgreSQL you can utilize the power of FDW (foreign data-tables wrapper) to bring Redis inside PostgreSQL.

Comment: This is a relative [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26046816/is-there-a-way-to-set-an-expiry-time-after-which-a-data-entry-is-automaticall) I have found **thanks to Ivo**'s comment.

Answer (score 0):

After some time evaluating the available solutions, this is the current situation, for folks who want to use the **Time-To-Live** (**TTL**) feature *within* **PostgreSQL**.

- **MongoDB**:

  > The background task that removes expired documents runs every 60 seconds.
- **Redis**:

  > Since Redis 2.6 the expire error is from 0 to 1 milliseconds.

For Redis there are two `fdw`s:

- [redis_fdw](https://github.com/pg-redis-fdw/redis_fdw) which:

  - is **active**, but
  - **doesn't support** the TTL feature, and
- [rw_redis_fdw](https://github.com/nahanni/rw_redis_fdw) which:

  - is **not active**,
  - **does support** the TTL feature, and
  - unfortunately **doesn't work** for Pg10.x

So, since I wanted to have *high resolution (small error) TTL within Pg10.x* I have used:

- Pg9.6 with **redis_fdw**, and
- Pg10.5 with **postgres_fdw**.

`postgres_fdw          redis_fdw
    PG10.5  ------------>  PG9.6  --------->  Redis`

PS: Data structure or any other feature was not important in this case. Only TTL.

## UPDATE

Now [rw_redis_fdw](https://github.com/nahanni/rw_redis_fdw) supports PostgreSQL10.x and 11.

Hence:

```
           redis_fdw
PG10.5/11  --------->  Redis
```