# How to store tempory data in hasura/postgresql database?

Tags: postgresql, hasura

How do I store temporary data in hasura/my postgresql database?
My usecase is for verificaion codes during onboarding (for example, email) which I don't want to have afterwards in the schema. (otherwise I'd have verification_x, verification_y, etc etc etc)

Comment: What do you mean by "temporary"? If it is not related to your other data, make a new schema for that.

Comment: As in, like a verification code that will be used once and then never needed again.

Comment: In some cases, temporary means "milliseconds" and during same session, in that case use a variable or maybe a temporary table. But if you send verification codes by email, that could be a week, in that case you put it in a table.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is more of a DB feature than a hasura thing.

The short answer is, no. This is not a feature of Postgres or Hasura. You can implement it relatively easily if you need to.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26063344/10290918) for a Postgres trigger based solution and for a comment downvoting this idea. Hasura also has [event triggers](https://hasura.io/docs/latest/graphql/core/scheduled-triggers/create-cron-trigger/) if you are more comfortable using a language like python or JS to implement this logic. Basically, an expiration (timestamp) column will allow you to determine when a record is expired. If (or how often) you choose to physically query and delete the expired records is your decision.